# Implement interface function as mapping property

Tags: solidity, interfaces

Why can we implement an interface function as mapping property? There's something on doc that explains this behaviour? I couldn't find anything related, but I'm assuming that a mapping property creates something like a function that has the same signature as expected on interface.

Also, there's some reason to do that and not create the function itself? I imagine that we can save some gas but that's it.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


interface ITest {
    function test(address addr) external view returns (address);
}

contract Test is ITest{
    mapping(address => address) public override test;
}
```